# Fetch "href" Information On Clicking a Button

Tags: javascript

I have to extract the "href" information of a button only if it is being clicked. The HTML tag corresponding to the button is:

```
<a class="donate" target="_self" rel="" href="/donate/donate-monthly">
```

How can I fetch the same using JavaScript?

Comment: And the JavaScript corresponding to HTML is: ...

Comment: Are you asking how to read an attribute value with JavaScript? Or how to respond to click events? Or how to make HTTP requests?

Comment: I am looking for a script that would fetch the "href" only when the event (clicking of a button) is triggered.

Comment: document.getElementById("idOfElement").getAttribute("href")

Comment: @Wridz — And which bit of that is causing you trouble? (If the answer is "all of it" then you should probably be reading an introductory JavaScript guide instead of diving straight into specific questions where, even after you've tried to clarify, I still don't know what you mean by *fetch the "href"*).

Answer (score -1):

First you should select your element with something like `var el = document.getElementById("yourId")` if you have an `id` attribute attached or `var els = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass")`.

*Note that `getElementById` will return single element if found but `getElementsByClassName` will return you all of the elements with this class so if you have more than 1 you will get an array.*

After you have selected you element lets say with `var el = document.getElementById("yourId")` you can extract the href with the `getAttribute()` method. So your code if you select by id will be like

```
var el = document.getElementById("someId");
var href = el.getAttribute("href");
console.log(href); // Or whatever you want to do
```

or if you select by class and you are sure that you have only 1 element with this class you can do

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("donate");
var el = els[0]; // The first element with this class
var href = el.getAttribute("href");
console.log(href); // Or whatever you want to do
```

*Note: If there are more elements you should find the correct index of the element you need.*

About the click part you should attach a eventListener so you can check when to extract the `href` like this:

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(){ // Where el is selected like in the examples above
    // Extract href
});
```